# Getting __ is not a function invalidvalue error while trying googlemaps with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I want to display map in my angularJS page like below.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="abc">
<div id="controller" ng-controller="def as ctrl">
    <div id="googlemap" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=displayMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my scripts.js file is as follows.

```
var mainApp = angular.module('abc',[]);
mainApp.controller('def', function($scope,$http) {

    this.displayMap=function() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            }

            $scope.googlemap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemap'), mapOptions);
        }

}
```

I am getting displayMap is not a function InvalidValueError message. How can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

`displayMap` function passed via callback parameter is expected to be visible from the *global scope* but in the provided example it is only accessible in the scope of `def` controller.

In Angular app instead of invoking `displayMap` function via `callback` parameter you could invoke it from the contoller like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', displayMap);
```

Example

```js
angular.module('mapApp', [])

    .controller("mapCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
       
        var displayMap = function (data) {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.209500, 16.370691),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), mapOptions);
        };

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', displayMap);

    });
```

```css
#map_div {
        height: 280px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
    <div id="map_div" ></div>
</div>
```